# Django Form and GET Param

Tags: django, forms, templates, get, view

I have this:

```
<form action='/ltsp' method='GET'>
    <label>Download Option:</label>
    <select name=''>
        <option name='download' value='download'>download</option> 
        <option name='show' value='show'>show</option>           
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Ausführen'>  
</form>
```

in my template. and it shows up like this '....de/ltsp?=download' in the url.Now in my view i want to check which (show/download) has been chosen. For now it looks like this:

```
def a(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        a = \
            A.objects.all().order_by('hostname').distinct()
        b = B.objects.all().order_by('name').distinct()
        if request.GET.get('name'):
            name = request.GET.get('ltsp', '')
            if name is 'download':
                response = render_to_response(
                    'thin/lts.conf', {
                        'a': a,
                        'b': b
                    }, mimetype='text/plain')
                response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; \
                    filename=lts.conf"
                return response
            elif name is 'show':
                return render_to_response(
                    'thin/lts.conf', {
                        'a': a,
                        'b': b
                    }, mimetype='text/plain')
            else:
                return HttpResponse(content="Failed", \
                    mimetype="text/plain", status=400)
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(content="Failed", mimetype="text/plain", \
                status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(content="Failed", mimetype="text/plain", \
            status=400)
```

Obviously doing this 'name = request.GET.get('ltsp', '')' is the wrong get. How do I get download or show from that form. I tried 'name = request.GET.get('name')' and name = request.GET.get('value') already. **Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the `select` a name and using that when getting the selected value:

```
name = request.GET['name-of-select']
```